# How do I call the function of the base class to show runtime polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-inheritance, run-time-polymorphism

There is a class Base which has a function add that inputs integers from the users and prints their sum. There's another class called Derived which publicly inherits the Base class and it also has a function add but it takes real numbers as inputs (basically float) and prints their sum.

Now what I want is for the user to input 2 numbers and the code to automatically know which function to call based on the type of input using runtime polymorphism.

For eg. if I give the inputs 2 and 3, it should print 5 and then "in base class" and if I give inputs as 3.5 and 2.5, it should print 6.0 and "in derived class".

The problem I'm facing with my code is that even if I'm giving the inputs as 2 and 3, it is calling the function of the derived class, as it is implicitly converting the integer inputs to float.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void add() {
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b;
        c = a + b;
        cout << c << endl;
        cout << "base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void add() {
        float a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b;
        c = a + b;
        cout << c << endl;
        cout << "derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* ptr;
    Derived d;
    ptr = &d;
    ptr->add();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried doing it normally and also tried using virtual but it's not helping.

Edit:

Here's the entire question:
Perform addition of two number using the concept of runtime polymorphism. Here, you have to create a Base class and Derived class. The Derived class should be derived from Base class and the both class will contain an add() function. In the Base class add() function is used to add two integers and in Derived class the add() function is used to add two real numbers. Finally, the real numbers addition will be displayed as the output.

Looks like it's just a dumb question

Comment: its a derived object, you call the method of the derived class via pointer to base. That is polymorphism.

Comment: _"... as it is implicitly converting the integer inputs to float"_ - that's not the reason. It calls `add` in `Derived` because that's the most derived type with an overridden `add` function. Just replace the content of the `add` functions with printouts. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/PzYe83jKb)

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how virtual functions work. By the time the user is entering values, it's already been decided whether you're in `Base::add` or `Derived::add`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes I know that it'll give priority to the derived function and immediately start with it. But that's what I've been asked to do, to show runtime polymorphism. What I want to confirm is that it's not possible with this specific example right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, even in the example you provided, it's going to call the derived function if I give int as input instead of float. so it's not possible to do it at runtime right? like i'll need to take the input in main and then call the parameterized function add

Comment: _"even in the example you provided, it's going to call the derived function if I give int as input instead of float"_ - In the example I made, you can't even give it any input, which was the point of the example. The selection of which overridden function to call is made just the same

Comment: I am afraid, we wont be able to solve the deeper issue here, that you misunderstood your task. You could try to include the exact text of the assignment in the quesiton, but actually I think it would be better to ask your tutor for clarification

Comment: From the description of your task you provided in a comment to an answer, I can only second the recommendation to return to your tutor. If that's the entirety of your task, it's pretty badly underspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what I want is for the user to input 2 numbers and the code to automatically know which function to call based on the type of input using runtime polymorphism.

This is not how polymorphism works. Virtual dispatch in a nutshell:

```
 ptr->add();
```

`ptr` is a pointer to `Base`. `Base::add` is virtual, hence the dynamic type of the object determines which method is called. The object is of type `Derived`, hence `Derived::add` is called.

This is how it is decided what method is called. Once called, it does not automatically get replaced by a different method depending on some user input.

Moreover, if you use `std::cin` to read integers, then the result will always be stored in that integers:

```
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b;
```

Entering `2.0` and `3.0` will not automagically turn `a` and `b` into `float`s. Similarly

```
    float a,b,c;
    cin >> a >> b;
```

If you enter `1` and `2` then the values stored in `a` and `b` are floating point numbers. The types of variables does not automatically change depending on user input.

Comment: Yes I get that. What I want to confirm is that in this specific scenario, where the user is entering the numbers, it's impossible to determine which add() it will call right? Because it's happening during runtime, it'll call whichever add has the higher priority

Comment: @TanishqKohli in the first half of the answer I try to explain that the user input has no influence whatsoever on whcih method is called. In your code `Derived::add` is called and that method prints `"derived"`, it cannot pritn something else.

Comment: @TanishqKohli btw there are no "priorities" here. `ptr->add()` can only call one method. The right one. And that is `Derived::add` because `ptr` does point to an instance of type `Derived` and `add` is virtual

Comment: @TanishqKohli it is possible to write code that calls different methods, depending on user input, but the code for this would be very different from yours, and I also do not see how polymorphism would fit in. As I commented above, the only way I see to clarify more is if you tell us what exactly is your task

Comment: Here's the entire question:

Perform addition of two number using the concept of runtime polymorphism. Here, you have to create a Base class and Derived class. The Derived class should be derived from Base class and the both class will contain an add() function. In the Base class add() function is used to add two integers and in Derived class the add() function is used to add two real numbers. Finally, the real numbers addition will be displayed as the output.

Comment: @TanishqKohli you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76524293/4117728) your question to include taht information

Comment: @TanishqKohli where did you get that task from? It sounds .... weird. It smells like overloading not like polymorphism or overriding. Unfortunately, those two concepts are sometimes confused in poor tutorials

Comment: @TanishqKohli if thats your task, no wonder you are confused

Comment: OK thank you for confirming I'm not the dumb one. It is from an assignment from my c++ class. I'll confront my professor about it. Because no matter what, the add() function of the base class will never be called. so it's pretty much useless

Comment: @TanishqKohli it is really unclear what you are supposed to do. The assignment text is strange and makes no sense. It could mean that you should write a `add(int,int)` and a `add(float,float)`, but as I said, this has nothing to do with polymorphism. I hope  they dont want you to write `Base::add(int,int)` and `Derived::add(float,float)`, because thats non-sense